# How to pass multiple queries into refetchQueries in apollo/graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a mutation named `deleteSong`. I was wondering after the mutation has passed through how can I pass multiple queries into `refetchQueries`?

```
 this.props
  .deleteSong({
    variables: { id },
    refetchQueries: [{ query: fetchSongs }] //<-- I only know how to pass 1 query
  })
  .then(() => {})
  .catch(err => {
    this.setState({ err });
 });
```

Comment: it's an array, no reasons you would not be able to pass multiples : `refetchQueries: [{ query: fetchSongs }, {query: fetchStuff}, {query: etc}]`

Comment: "With refetchQueries you can specify **one or more queries** that you want to run after a mutation is completed"  https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/docs/source/features/cache-updates.md#refetchqueries

Comment: @Ben have you tested this? I am on my phone atm and can't test till later. It makes since though, but if you have tested please put this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: I have't experienced that much apollo, but looking at your example and looking at the docs, it looked so obvious (you pass an array of hashes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Apollo Client documentation says the following about refetchQueries: *A function that allows you to specify which queries you want to refetch after a mutation has occurred*. So it should be possible for you to pass either a single or multiple queries to `refetchQueries()`.

Basically it should be:

```
 this.props
  .deleteSong({
    variables: { id },
    refetchQueries: [{ query: FETCH_SONGS }, { query: FETCH_FOLLOWERS }]
  })
  .then(() => {})
  .catch(err => {
    this.setState({ err });
 });
```

Whereas `FETCH_SONG` and `FETCH_FOLLOWERS` should be defined by [graphql-tag](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag). Maybe let others know if this solution works for you.